# Mi aplicacion desarrollada en python con flask al momento del despliege en apache2 error

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Muy buenas a todos, esta es mi primera pregunta, tengo una aplicación desarrollada en python 3.9, flask y mysql, en desarrollo todo bien, pero cuando esta desplegada con apache2 en ubuntu 20.04, todas las consulta que hago a la base de datos los esta devolviendo como lista, no importa si le especifico al cursor que lo quiero en diccionario, y ese es el problema, tengo consultas que la quiero en formato diccionario(Json) pero me están llegando en lista, ya he intentado todas las ideas que pasan por mi cabeza, necesito ayuda, no se si hay que configurar apache2.

aqui un ejemplo del codigo en python

```
@bp.route('/Login',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Login():
  try:
    if request.method=='POST':
      usuario=request.form['TxtUser']
      clave=request.form['TxtClave']
      # clave=base64.b64decode(clave).decode('utf-8')
      clave=base64.b64encode(clave.encode('utf-16le'))
      error=None
      if not usuario:
          error="El usuario es requerido"
      if not clave:
          error="La clave es requerida"
    
      user=Usua.Scuenta(usuario,clave)
      print(user)
      print(usuario)
      print(clave)
      if user ==[]:
          error="Usuario y/o contraseña inválido"
    
      if error is None:
          session.clear()
          for us in user:
              session.permanent = True
              session['idusuario']=us['idusuario']
              session['username']=us['nombre']
          msj=dict({'Estatus':'Exito','idresp':'','mensaje': url_for('Establecimiento.inicio')})
          return msj
    
      msj=dict({'Estatus':'Error','idresp':'','mensaje': str(error)})
      return msj
  except Exception as e:
      EscribirLog(str(e))
      msj=dict({'Estatus':'Error','idresp':'','mensaje': str(e)})
      return msj

  return render_template('Auth/Login.html')
```

Aqui el codigo de la funcion que realiza la consulta a mysql donde le especifico al cursor que quiero la respuesta en formato diccionario(JSON).

```
import mysql.connector as conn
from os import environ
from dotenv import load_dotenv

def Scuenta(*args):
  prm = list(args)
    try:
      load_dotenv()
      con = conn.connect(
          host = environ.get("HOST"),
          user = environ.get("DATABASE_USER"),
          password = environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
          port=environ.get("DATABASE_PORT"),
          database = environ.get("DATABASE")
      )
    
      cur= con.cursor(dictionary=True)
      cur.callproc("Susuario",prm)
      for result in cur.stored_results():
          resp=result.fetchall()
      con.commit()
      con.close()
      print("Prueba Impresion",resp)
      return  resp
  except conn.Error as ex:
      print("Error de conexion: {}".format(ex))
```

necesito ayuda.

Comment: listo ya esta arreglado.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias :-)

Answer (score 1):

para futuros yo y otros que tengan problemas para desplegar una aplicación flask, pude desplegar con exito mi aplicación desarrollada en python con el microframework flask en ubuntu 20.04, y para poder lograrlo use gunicorn y nginx, gunicorn es el servidor para ejecutar la app python y nginx para servir los archivos web, como los html,css,js. les dejare el link a la guiá que use, la cual me saco de un gran problema, use apache2 pero tube problemas, cabe destacar que si sus aplicaciones no llenan las session en la guiá hay una parte donde creas el servicio para gunicorn, donde tienes que borrar la opción que dice (--workers 3) esa parte era la que no dejaba que mis session llenaran.

Link:

(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04-es)